# Table border size is not working for mpdf

Tags: php, mpdf

Hi I am using mpdf for generating pdfs. Now I am facing problem with table border in html. I have following style for table in html

```
<table border="10" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 500px;">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Test header</td>
        <td>Test header</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

So the resulted pdf is not respecting the border size of the table. I attached the pdf. Please checj

Answer (score 9, accepted):

remove `border="10"` and use `border:10px solid` at style attribute for inline at `<table>` tag, `<tr>` and at `<td>` tags also as mpdf will work on inline style sheet for all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `inline css` ..

like
`<table style="border:1px solid black;">`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until i realised i had `$mpdf->simpleTables = true;`, borders showed up as soon as i set `$mpdf->simpleTables = false;`

Answer (score -1):

I had to do the trick:

For A4 pages, I've created a 794x1122px image [(example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5o1TG.png) , and set that image as a body background :

```
<?php
include_once(dirname(__file__).'/mpdf.php');
$mpdf=new mPDF( '',                          // mode (default '')
                'A4',  0, '',               // format ('A4', '' or...), font size(default 0), font family
                15, 15, 16, 16,     9,  9,  //(margins) left, right, top, bottom, HEADER, FOOTER
                'L');

$texttt= '<html><head><style>
            body {
            background:url("./background1.png") ;
            line-height:1.3em;
            background-color: #F2F0EE;
            }
            </style></head><body> 
            My Textttttt                 
            </body></html>';
$mpdf->WriteHTML($texttt);
$mpdf->Output('my_pdf_FILEEEEEE','F');
?>
```